# Android How do I prevent the use of a swift keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, autocompletetextview, swift-keyboard

i am developing a weather app. In an activity users can search cities. I used AutoCompleteTextView to searching. On using swift keyboard devices app is crashing with second letter on entering AutoCompleteTextView. On emulators or using other keyboards devices working properly. How do I prevent the use of a swift keyboard? I have to constraint keyboards.

Comment: Can't you try to solve the crash? Seems easier to me that trying to restrict user's keyboard

Comment: i have this log: W/InputMethodManager: IME died: com.touchtype.swiftkey/com/com.touchtype.KeyboardService.   As I said in my question my app is not crash on non-Swift keyboard.